# unable to access jarfile during docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am unable to resolve issue executing my run.sh file which invokes jar file within it. When i execute my run.sh file from my local, it works as expected.

docker file:

```
FROM maven:3.8.1-adoptopenjdk-11
WORKDIR /folder1
COPY folder1/ /folder1/
CMD ["/folder1/run.sh"]
```

run.sh file which resides within folder1

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar ".\test.jar" excel ".\\"
echo "Starting execution..."
read -t 5 -p "I am going to wait for 5 seconds only ..."
```

Commands executed:

> docker build -t demo3 .
>
> docker run -it -p 4044:4044 demo3

Error:

```
Unable to access jarfile .\test.jar
Starting execution...
```

Comment: Did you mean to use forward-slashes? `java -jar "./test.jar" excel "./"`

Comment: in my local where I am directly executing this run.sh file, I have used backslashes only and they work fine. I did try with forward slash after you mentioned and i still got the same error from docker run command